# If I have multiple instance of the same python application running how to perform logging into file?

Tags: python, logging, distributed-computing, multiple-instances

I have a worker application written in python for a distributed system. There is a situation when I need to start multiple instances of this worker on a single server. Logging should be written into file I suspect that I cannot write to the same file from different instances. So what should I do, pass log-file name as command line argument to each instance? Is there a standard approach for such situation?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Comment: Do you want the instances write in different files or not?

Comment: It is not very important while I can find the required info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use MySQL. This way I will have a standard tool for log analysis (MySQL Workbench), will solve the problem with multiple instance logging serialization. The best way would be probably to write a handler to standard logging module but at the moment I'll sent all messages through rabbitmq to service that stores them.